# Can you "doublesign" an android apk file?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, keystore

I did search the forum for a while but i did not find an answer for this. Recently, Google has changed its Maps API for android from v1 to v2. Since i started the project way before March, i was not aware they would not accept new apps working on the old API. Hence, it's just after i finished my app that i realized the Maps API key was tied to the keystore, and i cannot get a new Map API key for v1 now. And i would have to recode the entire thing to translate it to v2, which i cannot do right now.

My question is, is it possible to doublesign the .apk file and submit it to Google Play. Let's say i have a working .apk signed with my debug keystore. However, the .apk will not be accepted by Google because it uses the debug key. Can i then "resign" it with jarsigner to force Google Play to accept it? Will the app still work if i do this? Really would appreciate help for this asap. I don't have a timeline to recode the app now, and i really want to get visibility for the app in Google Play :/

Comment: AFAIK: Signatures are forever since Devices will only accept updates of an app if it has the same as before. The device validates that it's a legit update that way. If you need to change the signature, release it as a new app with a different package name (and redirect people from the old one there).

Answer (score 0):

> Can you “doublesign” an android apk file?

No. You can always sign the APK with any key, but that will just override old key.

> And i would have to recode the entire thing to translate it to v2

Unfortunatelly there is nothing else you can do except just that if you don't have a signing key and Maps v1 API key.

Comment: yeah i thought so as well, haiz have tried out all the options now. Thanks though.